# JPA replaces "true" by 1

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA with hibernate as persistence provider. PostgreSQL 9.1.5 is my database.

Query:

```
@Query("select COUNT(u) from User u where u.enabled=true")
```

is automatically translated to

```
select count(user0_.username) as col_0_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.enabled=1
```

As you can see "true" is replaced by "1". Postgre does't accept this query and error is thrown:

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select count(user0_.username) as col_0_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.enabled=1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
```

Query without replacement works fine. In pgadmin query interface the following query works.

```
select count(user0_.username) as col_0_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.enabled=true
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Which persistence provider you use (Hibernate? EclipseLink? OpenJPA?) and how is mapping for `User.enabled` look like? Do you have proper database dialect set in your ORM configuration?

Comment: I used ProgressDialect instead of PostgreSQLDialect. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using correct database dialect in your JPA provider. E.g. in Hibernate it should be:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```